# How to set system default line ending to CRLF mode for git in Cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin

Is there a way to set default line ending mode different from the system's (Cygwin's) default for git?

I use both Windos-Git (i.e. GitBash) and the native git on Cygwin.  The root cause of my problem is that CYGWIN considers itself a un*x, and thus the default line ending is set to LF.  However, CYGWIN runs on Windows, and most other cooperated software, including GitBash, want the line ending mode to be CRLF.

I use both because I administrate the git database, and need to assure usability of different git tools/clients for different engineers.

In Cygwin, When I set core.crlf to true, it won't convert text file to CR/LF for me, since Cygwin considers itself a un*x.

Is there a settings in GIT to tell git to force git to use CR/LF as it's 'auto' conversion default settings?  -OR- Any solutions for this situation?

Comment: Can you try again after setting `core.autocrlf` to false? (`git config --global core.autocrlf false`)

Comment: Since cygwin treats the system to be a un*x, setting core.autocrlf to true or false won't matter.   And yes, I tried.

Comment: I known, but since you are using `core.eol` directive in a `.gitattributes`, I just want to make sure there is no interference from the global config core.autocrlf (which applies blindly to *all* files). Can you test?

Comment: Actually, are you using core.eol? I am not familiar with "core.crlf".

Comment: @VonC: After some experiments, and reading each of the options very carefully, I know how to solve my problem... I will post it as an answer when I have time... And thanks to VonC's tip about core.eol.   It's part of the solution.

Comment: Great! I look forward reading that solution.

Comment: My problem actually got resolved using: `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long experiments with the confusion of other causes (including file execution bit problem, of which I mistakenly thought as line ending problem), finally I got the same conclusion as VonC's answer.  However, here I will post a more complete settings and explanations:

First of all, I will ask engineers to add following lines in their `~/gitconfig`, in the [core] section:

```
[core]
    filemode = false
    autocrlf = false
```

This fixes the file execution mode problem (`filemode` option), and forces git not to automatically doing crlf translation (`autocrlf` option).

Secondly, for windows, we will may optionally use this option.

```
[core]
    eol = crlf
```

This tells git to translate file marked as 'text' in `.gitattributes` to CR/LF line ending, if their line ending mode is not specified in `.gitattributes`. 
Note that this option is used by git ONLY when `autocrlf = false` in `.gitconfig` file.

We let the engineers to decide to use `eol = crlf` or even `eol = lf`, since they knows what line ending mode they like.

Lastly, for project's `.gitattributes`, we first categorize our text files into three groups: (A) text files that needs to have CR/LF line endings,  (B) text files that is generated by the tool/tool-chain (such as .xml files), which we won't edit them by text editors,  (C) text files that is OK to use either line ending modes (such as .cpp, .c, .h files).  Then we set our `.gitattributes` as follows:

```
*.<extension-for-groupA>    text    eol=crlf
*.<extension-for-groupB>    binary
*.<extension-for-groupC>    text
```

The third line is essential.  If the file is not marked as 'text', git will treat different line endings as some difference for a file in `git status`.

The second line has no effect, if the user's `.gitconfig` have `autocrlf = false`.  Yet for safety, we add this line.

An interesting setting is:

```
*.sh                 binary
```

For many regular shell scripts, use `*.sh  text eol=lf` should be fine.  However, those shell scripts with inline CR/LF special characters could be corrupted.

---

== UPDATE ==

Forgot to say, we still need to add/change `fileMode = false` in `[core]` section for remote repository, and/or local repository.   This is essential.  Local repository settings overrides users `.gitconfig` settings.

Comment: Nice and complete answer, more complete than mine. +1

Comment: Note, I believe the global config is in ~/.gitconfig, *not* ~/.git.config

Comment: Yes. .git.config is a typo.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Add SHELLOPTS igncr to your Windows environment variables.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the [gitattributes doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and "[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)" recommend:

```
*.<yourExtension> text eol=crlf
```

There is no "`core.crlf`"

```
text eol=crlf
```

> Git will always convert line endings to CRLF on checkout. You should use this for files that must keep CRLF endings, even on OSX or Linux.